# Cant run python script in Linux due to missing "requests" module

Tags: python, linux, pip, python-requests

I am running a python script in linux but it shows this error

```
python 47138.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "47138.py", line 11, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

I tried installing "requests" with pip and pip3 but both returned same output:

```
pip3 install requests
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (2.25.1)
```

Next i tried uninstalling requests but:

```
pip3 uninstall requests
Found existing installation: requests 2.25.1
Not uninstalling requests at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Can't uninstall 'requests'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

Comment: What is returned when you do `python -V`? You might need `python3 47138.py`.

Comment: python -V gives
Python 2.7.18 and python3 47138.py gives :     print r.text[0:dup]
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(r.text[0:dup])?

Comment: That's your issue, the python you are trying to execute your script with is version 2.7. You need to use Python 3, since that's where your requests module is installed.

Comment: it seems your script is written following `python2` syntax. `python3` syntax for print is `print()`. Either you need to install `requests` for `python2` or implement your script following `python3` syntax.

Comment: The recommendation would be to implement your script for `python3` as the earliest supported version is `python3.6`.

Comment: I installed requests for python 2 and worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Installed requests manually.

Clone the public repository:
$ git clone git://github.com/kennethreitz/requests.git

Download tarball:
$ curl -OL https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/tarball/master

$ python setup.py

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 install --force-reinstall requests
```

or

```
pip3 install --ignore-installed requests
```

to force reinstallation. See [the docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-force-reinstall).